# Trade still need 15 day hold even though steam guard is activated

Tags: steam

I trade with my friend and get 15 day hold because my steam mobile authenticator is not activated, then after i activate its still 15 days hold i dont know why its not updated to 6/7 day

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Steam's documentation of trade holds](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=8078-TPHC-6195) says:

> If you're trading items with a friend, and **you've been friends for more than 1 year**, the hold is 1 day.

> If you haven't had **your account protected by a Mobile Authenticator for at least the last 7 days**, items leaving your account will be held by Steam for up to 15 days. This provides you time to discover any transactions on hold that you didn't make.

So it sounds like you haven't been friends for long enough or haven't had your authenticator enabled for long enough. You just need to wait a few more days.